# wordpress woocommerce paypal standard payment

Tags: javascript, php

on wordpress client website i’m having problem during checkout of items using paypal standard payment,

example of one order:

the order was created on date 2023-07-24 after that i checked the notes order with the following message:

on 24 july 2023 at 15:59

60 minute pending stock applied to:
– MM Independent Sardegna Jet Helmet (MMSAR01M) Color: White Red, Helmets Sizes: M × 1

and then at 24 july 2023 17:02

Unpaid order canceled – time limit reached. The order status has changed from Awaiting Payment to Cancelled….

image of order –>https://ibb.co/7XFxQY1

even if wordpress said the order was cancelled the payment went smooth and the wordpress owner website received the payment that appear confirmed from his paypal account

the problem can be  this option that wasn’t flagged?

inventory option –> https://ibb.co/9nRQY4T

the problem of wordpress doesn’t appear with payment of paypal with 3 deferred payment and credit cards and other payment gateway allowed on woocommerce wordpress website client